# Prime divisors of sequences of integers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have the following problem and I need your support for it

> **Problem.** *Let P(x) be a polynomial with integer coefficients, such that $\deg P>0$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}P(x)=+\infty$. Prove that there exist infinitely many prime numbers $p$ such that for some natural number $n$
>   $$p\mid \left\lfloor \log\left(2017^{P(n)}+1\right)\right\rfloor.$$*

Comment: Do you know how to do it if you replace $\lfloor ... \rfloor$ with simply $Q(n)$ with $Q$ some polynomial ? If yes, it seems to me that the same kind of proof could apply, given that $\left \lfloor \mbox{log} \Big( 2017^{P(n)} +1 \Big) \right \rfloor - P(n) \mbox{log}(2017)$ is bounded

Comment: More precisely, the quantity $\lfloor ... \rfloor$ has a polynomial growth, and if your property was not true, it should have at least exponential growth (this is one possible way to prove that $\{ p \ \mbox{prime}\ |\ \exists n: \ p \mid Q(n) \}$ is infinite for $Q$ polynomial, $\mbox{deg}(Q)>0$).

Answer (score 1):

As I pointed out in my comments, what matters here is the growth. First we prove :

> **Proposition :** Given $f : \mathbb{N} \mapsto \mathbb{N}$ **strictly increasing**, and $k \ge 0$ such that $f(n) = O_{n \to +\infty} \big( n^k \big)$, the set $\{ p \mbox{ prime } | \ \exists n:\ p|f(n) \}$ is infinite.

*Proof :* ad absurdum, assume we can write this set $p_1, ..., p_r$. Let us denote $A = \{p_1^{k_1} \cdot\cdot\cdot p_r^{k_r}\ |\ k_i \ge 0\}$, $B = f(\mathbb{N})$, and for all $n$, $A_n = A \cap [\![1, n]\!]$ and $B_n = B \cap [\![1,n]\!]$. As $B_n \subset A_n$, $|B_n| \le |A_n|$.

However, as all $p_i$ are $\ge 2$, $|A_n| \le (\mbox{log}_2(n)+1)^r$.

And as $f$ is strictly increasing, $|B_n| = \max(\{m | f(m)\le n\})$. It is easy to conclude that $n^{1/k} = O_{n \to +\infty} (|B_n|)$.

Conclusion : $n^{1/k} = O_{n \to +\infty}\big( (\mbox{log}_2(n)+1)^r\big)$, which is absurd.

---

Regarding your problem, it is easy to check that $f :n \mapsto \left \lfloor \mbox{log}\Big( 2017^{P(n)}+1 \Big)\right \rfloor$ is strictly increasing (the quantity between the floor brackets increases by more than $\mbox{log}(2017)>1$ between $n$ and $n+1$).

Moreover, $f(n)\le P(n)*\mbox{log}(2017)+\mbox{log}(2017)+1$. We can apply the proposition.

Comment: If you drop the hypothesis 'P has integer coefficients' or depending on which log you want to use, it may become impossible to prove that $f$ is increasing. In this case consider simply $g : n \mapsto f(a \cdot n)$ for $a$ large enough.